# Scala: Primitive type hashCode uniqueness

Tags: scala

Just trying to clarify if next code will produce unique hash codes for primitive types:

```
val t = List(1, "test", 1232, 2.55, "Data", "Correct")
t.map(x => ClassTag(x.getClass).hashCode )
```

Here is what will be results of last line:

`res5: List[Int] = List(764977973, 1554547125, 764977973, 737810352, 1554547125, 1554547125`)

Can we assume that next hash codes will be will unique across different physical machines?

Comment: Never rely on hash for uniqueness of values.

Comment: I would like to transfer information regarding types in a collection, so it value mapped to a primitive type.

Comment: You can't even assume hashcodes are unique on the same machine.  Hashcodes purpose is not uniqueness.  If you need uniqueness across machines without communication, use a UUID.  If you want to send some information, serialize to known, meaningful data like the names of the types as strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash can, by *definition*, never be unique, ever. A hash maps a larger (potentially infinite) input space to a smaller (usually finite) output space. The Pigeonhole Principle says that there *must* be multiple input values that map to the same output value. (If you're not familiar with the Pigeonhole Principle, it is *really* simple: if you have three pairs of socks and two drawers, then no matter how you distribute the socks among the drawers there must be *at least one* drawer with *at least two* pairs of socks in it.)

There are infinitely many possible Scala objects but only finitely many hash codes, therefore, there must be at least one hash code that has infinitely many objects that map to it. In fact, since hash codes are usually written in such a way that they are well-distributed, *every* hash code will have infinitely many objects that map to it.

`hashCode`s are `Int`s. Which means that there are *exactly* as many `hashCode`s as there are `Int`s. So, if `hashCode`s *were* unique, then there wouldn't be any `hashCode`s left over for all the other objects (`Float`s, `Double`s, `Long`s, `String`s, `Char`s, `Boolean`s, `List`s, `Array`s, `Symbol`s, `Map`s, and so on and so forth). Just looking at `Long`s alone, there *must* be at least 4 billion `Long` objects which have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: I would assume you are talking about hash code collisions, different values produce same hash code. Is it still relevant in case extremely small input set of data? collection which will be always will be less than 100 elements i.e.